# Does caesium or francium have a lower ionization energy?

Tags: physical-chemistry, periodic-trends, ionization-energy

$\ce{Cs}$ and $\ce{Fr}$ are in the same group of lowest first ionization energy, but which element has the lowest ionization energy, and why?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Regarding your question, I've seen a lot of textbooks exclude Francium whenever they wanna compare periodic trends. It's good to check yours and see if it does that too, and in that case, inform us. :)

Answer (score 4):

> which element has the lowest ionization energy?

The ionization energy for Cs is lower than that of Fr.

> why?

The [Wikipedia article on Francium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francium) states:

> Francium has a slightly higher ionization energy than caesium, 392.811(4) kJ/mol as opposed to 375.7041(2) kJ/mol for caesium, as would be expected from relativistic effects, and this would imply that caesium is the less electronegative of the two.

That is, relativistic effects are more pronounced for francium than for cesium. A greater positive charge density in the nucleus for the larger atom (and higher atomic number) means higher velocity for (here) the 7s electron, which has a higher relativistic mass and thus stays closer to the nucleus than in the case of Cs (where we're dealing with the 6s electron).

The relativistic effect manifests in a greater effective electronic mass which in turn decreases the effective atomic radius, which makes it harder to pull off that electron (hence the higher ionization energy). See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_quantum_chemistry) for insights on atoms with a high atomic number and associated electrons with a low principal quantum number, my source for almost all of the answer contained in this post.